# Odd and Even HackerRank challenge

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to solve a problem on HackerRank and I sent the code, it worked in amost all the scnarios except for scnario 7 and 3 where they insert 18 and it should return "Weird" and when they insert 20 it should return "Weird" as well according to the website.

**The rules of the challenge are:**

> Given an integer, n, positive number from 1 to 100 , perform the following conditional actions:
>
> - If n is odd, print Weird
> - If n is even and in the inclusive range of 2 to 5, print Not Weird
> - If n is even and in the inclusive range of 6 to 20, print Weird
> - If n is even and greater than 20, print Not Weird Input Format
>
> A single line containing a positive integer, .
>
> Constraints
>
> Output Format
>
> Print Weird if the number is weird. Otherwise, print Not Weird.

**And my code was:**

```
n = 0
n = int(input('Type a number between 1 and 100: '))
odd = False
even = True

# ODD / EVEN
if (n%2) == 0:
    n = even #True
else:
    n = odd #False

# Is this odd or is this even?
if n == odd:
    print ('Weird')
    if n == even > 5 < 20:
        print('Weird')
elif n == even > 1 < 6:
    print ('Not Weird')
else:
    print('Not Weird')
```

I can't see what I did wrong, can you help me to solve it so it can work in all scnarios?

Comment: Range of what to what?

Comment: Your "rules of the challenge" don't include the required ranges to determine if your code works.

Comment: If you are going to dump some tasks on volunteers, please at least take care to copy the task description properly. You can [edit] your question to add the missing pieces. See also the [mcve] help page, since even with the missing information it is likely difficult to get the code working as-is.

Comment: What do you think ``n == even > 5 < 20`` actually means? Why do you test ``n == even ...`` inside a block that requires ``n == odd``?

Comment: I would say to be careful with Modulo: Modulo != Remainder.
"Remainder is simply the remaining part after the arithmetic division between two integer number whereas Modulus is the sum of remainder and divisor when they are oppositely signed and remaining part after the arithmetic division when remainder and divisor both are of same sign."

Comment: Also, don't abuse tags. You cannot have booth python-3.x and python-2.7 tags

Comment: Consider utilizing pythons ability to chain comparisons to [improve readability](https://replit.com/@ShashSinha1/StupendousSquareEditor#main.py)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I assume `if n == even > 5 < 20:` shouldn't be tabbed in.

Comment: I think its better to solve it for your self, it seems you need that training. but you can ask for hints. if you reconsider. `if my_input % 2 == 0` what should that statement print? I think you are overworking this.

Comment: @buran are you saying you can't produce code that works in 3 and 2? That's a false claim. If you're claiming you need to reduce your platform based on the rules for stackoverflow questions I might concede to that.

Comment: @NationWidePants, in this case you should use just generic `python` tag. Check the description of e.g. `python-2.7` tag: _Do not add this tag simply to convey the version of Python you're using, **unless the question concerns an issue specific to Python 2.7**._ Same for `python-3.x` tag.

Comment: @NationWidePants, check also [_Tagging Recommendations_ section](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot to unpick here. As this is an assignment, I'm not going to print the full solution out here, but I will point out the mistakes you've made so you can come to the correct solution.

First issue: reassigning 'n'.

You assign the value from the input to n, then subsequently replace it with the value of odd or even. This means you have lost the original input number. Instead you should assign the result to a new variable (such as 'isEven').

Second issue: uneccesarry 'if'

The result of 'n%2 == 0' is already True/False, depending if n is an even/odd number. So you can simply assign the result, rather than use an 'if' block.

Third issue: multiple operators

Logical operators have an order of operation, and resolution. The statement 'n == even > 5 < 20' makes no logical sense. Instead you should do independent Boolean comparisons, and join them with "and" or "or". E.g. 'if isEven and n < 5 and n> 20'.